# The problems view states that project cannot be build, until path errors are resolved

Tags: eclipse, java

I'm using Eclipse Indigo IDE, and upon changing my project compliance level to JDK 1.7, it gives me a red exclamation over the java project file, and doesn't compile any of my source code. Is there any any way to solve this problem?

Comment: why you changed it to 1.7 version ?

Comment: Most likely yes.  See in the "Markers" view _why_ the red exclamation is there.

Comment: What is the details of the error? What does the Problems view tell you about it?

Comment: The problems view states that project cannot be build, until path errors are resolved.

Comment: Is that the *only* thing it says?  Do you actually have a 1.7 JRE set up with the Installed JREs Preference Page?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem of JDK, you specify in your IDE a jdk who don't exist in your computer. Install it !

Answer (score 0):

Click right on your project and properties after look at 'project facets' and change Java compiler. I hope help you.

Comment: Did what you said, but I still have that problem

Comment: Then, write your question well. This is a bad question.

Answer (score 0):

The responses before are correct, but you need to apply both of them.

1º- You need install jvm 1.7 in your system and configure it in Eclipse.
2º- Go to Project properties-> Compile and select version 1.7
3º- In project properties->project facets select Java compiler 1.7

I hope help you.

Comment: My workspace default is 1.6, and it doesn't seem to be working. I did what you said.

Comment: What type of project did you created? Dynamic Web, Java Project, Maven Project???

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether your project is building automatically. In workbench bar project->build automatically if not ticked then tick it.
you can go for project clean.
I hope this works if you have proper installation of JRE, and selected the proper check of windows->preferences->installed jre.